# Laravel Join Query

Tags: php, sql, join, laravel

To make it simple, I have the following models.

```
User Model:
Has_Many('Campaign')

Campaign Model
Has_Many('Schedule')
Belongs_to('User')

Schedule Model
Belongs_to('Campaign')
```

I'd like to get all Schedules that belong to campaigns that belong to the logged in user.

At first I thought I could do something like this

```
$user->campaign->schedules;
```

But apparently I cannot...

What would be the best way to get it?

Comment: show your models/methods.

Comment: The models are listed above, is anything else necessary? It's more of a logic issue..

Comment: campaign is a collection, loop through them and select all the schedules for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
// Controller
$user = Auth::user()->with('campaigns.schedules')->first();
return View::make('user.schedule_lists')->with('user', $user);

// View (Blade Templating)
{{ $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name }}
@foreach($user->campaigns as $campaign)
    <h2>{{ $campaign->campaign_field_name }}</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach($campaign->schedules as $schedule)
           <li>{{ $schedule->schedule_field_name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

**Update:** I've demonstrated the process using imaginary view name and table's field names.